# Multicolor text in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, drawtext

How to use drawtext in ffmpeg to draw multicolor text over video? 
Example: I want to highlight a proper nouns in a sentence, 
"XYZ company shares hike 91%"
highlight XYZ white yellow
highlight 91% with green

If you have any other approach not using ffmpeg to draw multicolor text over video, that would work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Make ASS subtitles in [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/) (or manually) and use the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter in `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf subtitles=colors.ass -c:a copy output
```

Example ASS file contents:

```
[Script Info]
; Script generated by Aegisub 3.2.2
; http://www.aegisub.org/
Title: Default Aegisub file
ScriptType: v4.00+
WrapStyle: 0
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
YCbCr Matrix: None

[Aegisub Project Garbage]

[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,20,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H00000000,0,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,1,2,2,2,10,10,10,1

[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\c&H00FFFF&}XYZ {\c&HFFFFFF&}company shares hike {\c&H00FF00&}91%
```

Alternative but not recommended method is to use separate drawtext instances for each color.

Comment: Thanks LordNeckbeard, but using subtitles filter, I cannot animate the text (like left to right movement)

Comment: @Holy_diver ASS allows animation of various types. See the [`\move` tag](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#movement) among others.